# Measure from on product $\sigma$-algebra to on component $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

This is inspired by [Carl Offner's reply to one of my previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23009/from-sigma-algebra-on-product-space-to-sigma-algebra-on-component-space/23014#23014) and [my previous question about marginal and joint measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23070/how-to-understand-marginal-distribution).

1. Given a measure $\mu$ on product
   $\sigma$-algebra $\prod_{i \in I}
   \mathbb{S}_i$ of a collection of
   measurable spaces $(X_i,
   \mathbb{S}_i), i \in I$, does there
   exist a measure $\mu_i$ on each
   component $\sigma$-algebra
   $\mathbb{S}_i$, s.t. their product
   $\prod_{i \in I} \mu_i$ is the given
   measure $\mu$ on the product
   $\sigma$-algebra?
2. If no, what are some necessary and/or
   sufficient conditions for the given
   measure $\mu$ to have such a
   decomposition?
3. When they exist, how to construct
   the component measures $\mu_i$ from
   $\mu$?

   For example, is this a viable way
   by defining  $$\mu_i(A_i):=
   \frac{\mu(A_i \times \prod_{j \in
   I, j\neq i} X_i)}{\prod_{j \in I,
   j\neq i} \mu_j(X_i)}, \forall A_i \in \mathbb{S}_i ?$$ If not,
   when will it become viable?  ADDED: I asked this question, because obviously, the product and the division may not make sense in some cases. Also I actually made a mistake of circular definition, where I define $\mu_i$ in terms of $\mu_j, j\neq i$ which have to be defined in similar ways.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: As was noted in your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21945/infinite-product-of-measurable-spaces, there is an important difference between products of *measurable* spaces and products of *measure* spaces. The former always exists and is given by the categorical product, but the latter may not even exist.

Comment: Your quotient may not even make sense. If one $X_i$ has infinite measure, then what does it mean to take the quotient? The product may not make sense; if one of the $X_i$ has infinite measure, and the other has measure zero, what does it meant to take their product? What is the product of an infinite number of factors? Of an *uncountable* number of factors?

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks! As to your latest comment, I have thought about that. So Whenever possible, what are the possible ways to go from a measure on product sigma algebra to measures on component sigma algebra, s.t. their product is the given measure?

Comment: @Tim: You're going to have huge problems even trying. Take $X_i$ the $2$-element set, $\mathbb{S}_i$ the total $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu_i$ the counting measure, and $I$ uncountably infinite. No way to construct a product measure, because all the sets in $\prod S_i$ are uncountable, and no way to recover the counting measures from a measure on the product. Again, there may not even **be** a reasonable measure on the product because the projections are not measure invariant, even in the simple case of, say, $[0,1]$ with the Borel measure, and the product of two factors.

Comment: @Arturo: could you elaborate a little more on your last comment on the `measure invariant'? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim: Your previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21945/infinite-product-of-measurable-spaces has an answer from Pete, which in turn has a comment directing to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49426, which talks about the fact that the projections are not measure preserving (so the measure is not invariant under projections). If you pull back a measurable set, the measure of the pullback is not necessarily equal to (or every proportional to) the measure of the original set. Conversely, the measure of a projection is not necessarily well-related to the measure of the set

Comment: @Arturo This answers actually my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to (1) is certainly no; not every measure on a product space is a product measure, not even for a finite product.  Consider for example the following: let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, let $F : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ be given by $F(x) = (x,x)$, and let $\mu = m \circ F^{-1}$ be the pushforward measure on the product $[0,1]^2$ (with its product $\sigma$-algebra of course).  $\mu$ then is effectively 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the diagonal of $[0,1]$.  Now $\mu$ cannot be a product measure.  For suppose $\mu = \mu_1 \times \mu_2$.  Let $0 < a < 1$; it's clear that we have $\mu((0,a)^2) = a > 0$ and $\mu((a,1)^2) = 1-a > 0$.  Thus $\mu_i((0,a)) > 0$ and $\mu_i((a,1)) > 0$ for $i=1,2$.  But $\mu((0,a) \times (a,1)) = \mu((a,1) \times (0,a)) = 0$, a contradiction.

This is best thought of in terms of probability theory: a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ gives the (joint) distribution of a random vector $(X_1, \dots, X_d)$.  If $\pi_i : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,\dots,d$ is the projection onto the $i$'th component, then $\mu_i = \mu \circ \pi_i^{-1}$ is the marginal distribution of $X_i$.  But $\mu$ is a product measure iff $\{X_1, \dots, X_d\}$ are independent.  In our example, $\mu$ is the joint distribution of $(U,U)$, where $U \sim U(0,1)$; obviously $U$ is not independent of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I answer 2 and 3 for the case of probability measures, the only measures one can sensibly take infinite products of. So all measures will be understood to be probability measures.

Let the measure $\mu_i:\mathbb{S}_i\to[0,1]$ be given by $\mu_i(S)=\mu\big(\pi_i^{-1}(S)\big)$. If $\mu$ can be written as an infinite product measure, it must be the product of the $\mu_i$, which answers 3 once we have settled the issue of when we can decompose $\mu$.

This is the case if and only if  for every finite set $F\subseteq I$ and any infinite product of measurable sets $A=\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ such that $A_i=X_i$ for all $i\notin F$ (we call such sets *measurable rectangles*), we have $\mu(A)=\prod_{i\in F}\mu_i(A_i)$. This is clearly satisfied for product measure spaces. Conversely, measurable rectangles generate the product $\sigma$-algebra and are closed under finite intersections, so a measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra is determined by the values on these sets and the product of probability spaces [always exists](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-19/issue-3/Notes-on-infinite-product-measure-spaces-I/10.3792/pia/1195573633.full).

Comment: Thanks! "probability measures, the only measures one can sensibly take infinite products of". Why is it not sensible to take infinite product of non probability measures?

Comment: I guess the idea is that an infinite product of positive numbers can only converge to a finite nonzero limit if they converge to $1$ (and rather quickly). Hence, the condition that $\mu_i(X_i)$ almost $1$ is necessary to get a non trivial product of the $\mu_i(X_i)$.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason. In particular, we usually want to have products where all factor are the same.